# Css Circle and text inline

Tags: css, alignment, shapes, geometry, text-alignment

Hello i need to have a css circle and on right a text, inline.

I use this code

```
<div class="circlearancione">Disponibile</div>

.circlearancione{
background-color: red;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-width: 5px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}
```

But using this my text not have any space between circle and text. I try to use margin and padding but nothing change.

Also try to use

```
 <div class="circlearancione"></div><p>Disponibile</p>

.circlearancione, p { display: inline; }
```

But with this not display the circle.

What's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: In the first one, the text is inside the div, thus inside the circle. In the second one, give the div a width and hieght and see what happens

Comment: I think you need to enclose the text either in a div or a span instead of a p and then give it a margin left. And yes, as sn3ll says, having the text inside the circle won't help. :P

Answer (score 4):

You can use `:before` pseudo-element for circle and `Flexbox` for vertical alignment.

```css
.circlearancione {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  background-color: red;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circlearancione">Disponibile</div>
```

You can also put your text in `span` and add it some `margin-left`.

```css
.circlearancione {
  background-color: red;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
span {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circlearancione"><span>Disponibile</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use simple flex to achieve it. It promotes **fluid**, **responsive**, **scalable** and **readable** structure.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="circlearancione"></div>
  <p>Disponibile1</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="circlearancione"></div>
  <p>Disponibile2</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="circlearancione"></div>
  <p>Disponibile3</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

p { margin:0; }
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.circlearancione{
  background-color: red;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}

p { margin:0; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circlearancione"></div>
  <p>Disponibile1</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="circlearancione"></div>
  <p>Disponibile2</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="circlearancione"></div>
  <p>Disponibile3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine something like this if you would like to avoid using flex.

```css
.circlearancione {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  background-color: red;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>
    <span class="circlearancione"></span>Disponibile
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to place a span within your div that will act like the circle

```
<div class="circlearancione"><span></span> Disponibile</div>
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v5LLp7uf/